# Different options for subdirectories in NFS exports

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I have the following `/etc/exports` config for my NFS server for use as kubernetes data volumes:

```
/data                10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_root_squash)
/data/heavy-write    10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync)
```

where  /data, and /data/heavy-write are mounted disks.

In `/data` i have a few directories which are part the /data filesystem:

```
/data/homes
/data/git
```

I want to be able to remove `no_root_squash` from `/data` and add it only to one of the subdirs `/data/homes`. I've trieds having another entry in `/etc/exports` and it didn't seem to work.

```
/data                10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync,fsid=0)
/data/homes          10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/data/heavy-write    10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync)
```

Comment: Did you try adding no_subtree_check option for /data/homes export ?

Comment: Didn't work: `/data 10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync,fsid=0)` `/data/homes 10.100.100.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`